# Melhorar script de classificação (star rating)

Tags: php

Tem como melhorar esse código ?

```
<?php
            if ($calculation >= 5)
            {
                for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
                {
                    echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star1_16x16.png"> ';
                }
            }
            elseif ($calculation >=3 && $calculation <5)
            {
                for ($i=1;$i<=$calculation;$i++)
                {
                    echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star1_16x16.png"> ';
                }
                for ($calculation;$calculation<5;$calculation++)
                {
                    echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star_16x16.png"> ';
                }
            }
            elseif ($calculation <=2)
            {
                for ($i=1;$i<=$calculation;$i++)
                {
                    echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star1_16x16.png"> ';
                }
                for ($calculation;$calculation<5;$calculation++)
                {
                    echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star_16x16.png"> ';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star_16x16.png"> ';
            }
            ?>
```

Essa é a função dele:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais ele buga quando tem menos de 3 pontos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra que os ifs? O for já nao resolvia? O que muda se forem 5 ou se forem duas? Eu acho que só isso basta: `for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) echo '<img src="'.$linkSite.'/img/star'.($i>$calculation?'1':'').'_16x16.png">';`

Comment: Sim é possível, acredite!

Comment: Sugiro fazer em javascript e css pois é algo visual que não precisa ser processado no server. A menos que tenha um motivo muito específico para renderizar no server. Veja um exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css/1987545#1987545

Comment: Na verdade, isso é caso pra CSS puro, e só mudar a classe pelo PHP.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado!!

Comment: @DanielOmine Vou tentar isso ai, parece que vai deixar melhor o sistema :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creio que algo como isso já seria o suficiente

```
$nota = 3.6;

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    if($i <= $nota) {
        echo '<img src="estrela_ativa.png" />';
    }
    else {
        echo '<img src="estrela_inativa.png" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ficou uma versão mais complexa do que eu pus no comentário :) De qq forma, entendo que tá certa. +1

Comment: Verdade, vi a sua somente depois rsrs, posta ela como resposta

Comment: Resposta de uma linha só é sacanagem :) Se quiser "importar" ela na sua, fique à vontade. Só confira a sintaxe, escrevi meio rapidinho só pra ilustrar.

Comment: Rsrs, mas é a reposta que ele precisa kkkkk, é que eu gosto de fazer em várias linhas, eu acho melhor para leitura do código

Comment: @JefersonAssis Sim, deu certo! Obrigado